# Metadata Location For 'Topic Assignment Rule' aka 'Automatic Topic Assignment'

Tags: community, metadata, topics, data-category

For a Community, in the Workspace 'Content Management', there's an option for 'Automatic Topic Assignment' that lets you set rules to automatically assign topics to new articles of a specific data category. This works great...but where does this metadata live?

I can pull down the Data Category Groups and the Managed Topics, but neither of those seem to have a reference to this information. I feel like there's some sort of 'Topic Assignment Rule' somewhere that I'm missing.

Or does this just have to be a post-deployment step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet exposed via the Metadata API. Hence you will have to manually do it again in the Production application as of Today.

I confirmed with the Salesforce Metadata API team.